# Bootstrap 3 nesting tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating an application and there's a lot of content so I am putting them in nested tabs. All works well except when I click on the nested tab, the content does not show.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#minecraft" data-toggle="tab">Minecraft</a></li>
  <li><a href="#website" data-toggle="tab">Forums</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pokemasters" data-toggle="tab">Pokemasters</a></li>
  <li><a href="#runerage" data-toggle="tab">Rune Rage</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="minecraft">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="pills">
      <li class="active"><a href="#minecraft-registration" data-toggle="tab">Minecraft Registration</a></li>
      <li><a href="#minecraft-rules" data-toggle="tab">Rules</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="minecraft-registration">
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="minecraft-registration">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="website">Forums</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pokemasters">Pokemasters</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="runerage">Rune Rage</div>
</div>
```

The code above produces this:
[image: http://gyazo.com/1657f7656a92ffd19926766ceee99402.gif]

It's functional however, the content of the nested tab isn't shown. The content should show
`test` but it's blank.

Answer (score 1):

Nested tabs is not like this in bootstrap. You should use Dropdowns.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/BxUx9/)**

**HTML**

```
   <li class="dropdown active">
          <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Minecraft <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
            <li class=""><a href="#minecraft" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Minecraft Registration</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#minecraftrules" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Rules</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 divs with same id. That is the problem. Remove the extra div as shown below.

Convert

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="minecraft-registration">

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="minecraft-registration">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="minecraft-registration">
    test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similor problem: Fixed it as follows: Try this :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <!-- Custom Tabs -->
          <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#set1">New</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#set2">Confirmed</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">

        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="set1">

            <div class="tabbable">
                 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Web Design and Development</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Domain Registration</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Cloud Computing Services</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_4" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Android application Development</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_5" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Web Hosting</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_6" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">SEO and Online Marketing</a></li>
              <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
                <b>Web Deign and development hires:</b>




                <table class="table" id="webdesignTable">                   
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>



              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
              <b>Domain Registration</b>


              <table class="table" id="domainregistrationTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>



              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_3">
               <b>Cloud Computing</b>


              <table class="table" id="cloudcomputingTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->

              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_4">
               <b>Android application Development</b>


              <table class="table" id="androidappTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->

              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_5">
               <b>Web Hosting</b>


              <table class="table" id="webhostingTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->

              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_6">
               <b>SEO and Online Marketing</b>


              <table class="table" id="seoTable">                   
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.tab-content -->
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="set2">
            <div class="tabbable">
                   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Web Design and Development</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Domain Registration</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Cloud Computing Services</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_4" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Android application Development</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_5" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Web Hosting</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#tab_6" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">SEO and Online Marketing</a></li>
              <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
                <b>Web Deign and development hires:</b>




                <table class="table" id="webdesignTable">                   
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>



              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
              <b>Domain Registration</b>


              <table class="table" id="domainregistrationTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>



              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_3">
               <b>Cloud Computing</b>


              <table class="table" id="cloudcomputingTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->

              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_4">
               <b>Android application Development</b>


              <table class="table" id="androidappTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->

              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_5">
               <b>Web Hosting</b>


              <table class="table" id="webhostingTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->

              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_6">
               <b>SEO and Online Marketing</b>


              <table class="table" id="seoTable">                   
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>Order By</th>                                                   
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Message</th>
                            <th>Date</th>                                               
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.tab-pane -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.tab-content -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```